# How to get this template class to compile?

Tags: c++, templates

Sorry, I couldn't frame a question that could capture my problem properly. My problem is this.

I have a templated class like this. I am not able to understand how exactly to define the Get function.

```
template<class Data>
class Class
{
    struct S
    {
    };
    void Do();
    S Get();
};

template<class Data>
void Class<Data>::Do()
{
}

template<class Data>
Class<Data>::S Class<Data>::Get()
{
}
```

I get the following errors

```
1>error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'Class<Data>::Get'
1>error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
```

Comment: A nicer compiler prints: 'error: need ‘typename’ before ‘Class<Data>::S’ because ‘Class<Data>’ is a dependent scope'

Comment: struct Class<Data>::S Class<Data>::Get()
{
}

Comment: @Dieter Which might that be?

Comment: @george your suggestion 'struct Class<Data>::S Class<Data>::Get() { }'  doesn't work, I get redefinition error. However, typename does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template<class Data>
Class<Data>::S Class<Data>::Get()
```

needs to be

```
template<class Data>
typename Class<Data>::S Class<Data>::Get()
```

because `S` is a dependent type. Any time you have a type that's nested in a template you need to use the keyword `typename`. For example, an iterator over a `vector<int>` has the type `typename vector<int>::iterator`.

Comment: `typename vector<int>::iterator`: `typename` keyword is possible, but not necessary in this case (in C++11). In C++03 it is not possible to use `typename` keyword outside templates (even in full specializations).

Answer (score 0):

A C++11 style, easier to read and write :

```
template<class Data>
auto Class<Data>::Get() -> S {
    return {};
}
```